# How to query data from a object URI in sparql

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, semantic-web

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://localhost/mydata#"
     xml:base="http://localhost/mydata"
     xmlns:g="http://localhost/mydata/"
     xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://localhost/mydata">
        <owl:imports rdf:resource="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/travel.owl"/>
        <owl:imports rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"/>
    </owl:Ontology>
</rdf:RDF>
```

I have my RDF in the above format. I wish to query the data in the resource http://www.owl-ontologies.com/travel.owl as well. How can I do it? I get the URI value using the below query but shall be done next?

```
    prefix ab:<http://www.owl-ontologies.com/travel.owl#>
prefix rdfs:<https://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix owl:<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
SELECT ?y
WHERE { ?x owl:imports ?y.
  ?
}
```

Comment: not possible. You have to load the data into the triple store/data engine. Then you can query it

Comment: I am a newbie with this. Can you tell me how load it into the triple store or data engine? I am curently using Fuseki to query the data.

Comment: I suggest you have a look at https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/index.html